# Remove space between sections in collectionview

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, collectionview, uicollectionreusableview

How to adjust the spacing between sections of collection view.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Header height can be adjusted by adjusting the params of the collection view layout. Following is the code which works perfectly fine.

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if ([[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
      return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the method to implement this:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section 
{
    //{top, left, bottom, right}

    if ([[sectionHeaderStatusArray objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(23, 19, 46, 14);
    }

      return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Here's the Swift 4.2 version.**

This lets you set various inset configurations for different sections.

```
/// Formats the insets for the various headers and sections.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    if section == 0 {
        // No insets for header in section 0
        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
    } else {
        // Normal insets for collection
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a layout issue, thus the answer will be in whatever layout you're using for the collection view. If you're using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` then you'll want to set the `sectionInset`. e.g.

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Comment: Give more information then. What layout are you using? I think you need to investigate into whatever layout it is.

Comment: For flow layout you can do this
if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        }

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if ([[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
    }
      return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```