# How to remove space between section in UICollectionView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with two section. In first, it has `UIPageControl` and in second simple `UICollectionView`. 
 Between first and second element it has spacing,  can you suggest me how to remove that?

[image]

**Platform iOS 9.*, Swift 3**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove space between sections in collectionview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386506/remove-space-between-sections-in-collectionview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the UIEdgeInsets of the collection view to solve this problem

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }
```