# How to remove horizontal spacing between cells in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I want to place 6 cells in two rows and having spacing = 1 between cells, I have tried the minimalLineSpacing method but it works between cells not between rows. Is there any trick or suggestions to achieve that? here is what i have tried so far: [image: here is how it look like now]
and [image: it is how i make the size of the cells]

and i [image: used this mehtods to achive spacing = 1 between cells]

Comment: Check these links:-

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325277/how-to-set-cell-spacing-and-uicollectionview-uicollectionviewflowlayout-size-r
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386506/remove-space-between-sections-in-collectionview

Answer (score 0):

```
// spacing between cells
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return cellSpacing
}
// spacing between rows
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return cellSpacing
}
```